# Appending to an array that's tied to an Angular.JS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

In one of my Angular.JS controllers, I have the following:

```
app.controller("MyController", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.messages = [
        new Message(1),
        new Message(2)
    ];
    $scope.addMessage = function(x) { $scope.messages.push(new Message(x)); }
}]);
```

Then in my main HTML page, I have

```
<message message="message" ng-repeat="message in messages">
```

This is bound to a directive:

```
app.directive("message", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            message: "="
        },
        templateUrl: "js/Directives/message.html"
   };
});
```

The template file is:

```
<li class="message">{{message.msg}} </li>
```

However, when I call addMessage on the controller, while it does add to `$scope.messsages`, it doesn't actually refresh the ng-repeat and display the new message. How can I do this?

Comment: Does your directive create a new scope or it inherits the existing one ??. Using a service to share these values will be a better idea, it saves you from the ng-repeat scope fiasco..

Comment: @ManishKr.Shukla I've added the directive code to the question; I'm afraid I'm new to Angular and don't quite know.

Comment: Type angular.element($0).scope(); into the console of your browser to inspect the $scope - find the array messages to see that the message really is added to the collection. PS you need to select an angular html element - right click on an html angular element, and click "Inspect element", then go to the console and type in "angular.element($0).scope();"

Comment: @Will Yep, the new message shows up

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest some structural changes in your directive.

First of all, why not refer the original array itself instead of referring value at each iteration ??

```
<message messages="messages">
```

Then you can actually move ng-repeat part in your directive template, [You must note that since you're using = in `message: "="`, = binds a local/directive scope property to a parent scope property. So with =, you use the parent model/scope property name as the value of the DOM attribute. ].

Hence your directive will look like :

```
app.directive("message", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            messages: "="
        },
        templateUrl: "js/Directives/message.html"
   };
});
```

and the subsequent template will look something like this :

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="message in messages" class="message">{{message.msg}} </li>
    </ul>
```

You can find a demo plunker [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6s307vs8/2/)

Comment: So very clearly, your demo works, but I can't seem to get it to work in my code unless I use the $scope.$apply() that someone else suggested. Does that suggest I have a scoping problem somewhere?

Comment: The plunker works without using $scope.$apply(), so why is it required in your implementation ??